# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in xamarin.android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I get this exception when I click the button in my fragment.
Below is the code for my fragment

```
    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            int pos = position + 1;
            if (pos == 1) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From (container.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.AddView (view);
                return view;
            } else if (pos == 2) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From (container.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.BookAService, container, false);
                Spinner spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner);
                var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource (
                                  container.Context, Resource.Array.planets_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);

                adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);
                spinner.Adapter = adapter;
                var sel = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    Button but = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonservice);
                try{
                    but.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                        ParseObject Service = new ParseObject("Services Ordered");
                        Service["userid"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser.ObjectId;
                        Service["Name"] = sel;
                        Service["Username"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Get<String>("Name");
                        await Service.SaveAsync();
                        Toast.MakeText(container.Context,"Your Service request is taken and our will be processed within One hour",
                        ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    };
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.MakeText (container.Context, e.ToString (), ToastLength.Long).Show ();
                }
                container.AddView (view);
                return view;


            } else {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From (container.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.LogIn, container, false);
                container.AddView (view);
                return view;
            }
        }
```

When I click the button in the fragment the code throws an exception as

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I also tried to catch the exception and toast it to screen but it didn't help.
Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Use the debugger, to find out which exact line fails...

Comment: Is the code correct for fragments? @Cheesebaron

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the space in declaring the Parse Object.

```
    ParseObject Service = new ParseObject("Services Ordered");
```